# Does "made cut, did not finish" also count as a "missed cut?"

Tags: terminology, golf, pga-tour

At the 2014 Farmers Insurance Open, Tiger Woods finished with a result of "MDF" or "made cut, did not finish." This is the first time in his career he has had a MDF.

A missed cut (MC) is the result when a player finishes outside the top-70 and ties after the second round.

When more than 78 players advance into the third round, a MDF is the result when a player finishes outside the top-70 and ties after the third round. This is also known as a "54-hole cut."<sub>[(1)](http://www.golfchannel.com/news/doug-ferguson/woodland-leads-spieth-woods-has-first-career-mdf/)</sub>

**Does "made cut, did not finish" also count as a "missed cut?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not.

Notice from the [leaderboard](http://www.pgatour.com/content/pgatour/tournaments/farmers-insurance-open/leaderboard.html) of this year's Farmers Insurance Open that Tiger Woods finished "MDF." Next, take a look at the consecutive cuts made [statistics](http://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.122.html), where Tiger is currently T4 with 24 consecutive cuts made.